# How do I reset toggles in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I would like to reset my toggles after on changing the drop down list item.

I have already tried to create a variable in the Toggle Reset, but there is still error...

```
UpdateContext({ResetToggle:true})
```

I would like to on change the item in drop down list to be able to reset toggles, but, my Toggle reset does not work.

Please look at the images below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the controls on the same screen? I mean the dropdown and the toggle button.
Because if they are not, then it will not work because the ResetToggle you used is a contextual variable.
You can however share the picture of the error notification you are getting on the Toggle button formula bar.

Comment: They are in different screen. Can u give me an example of how I can reset the toggles :( @Akande Babatunde

Comment: You will have to use a global variable instead of the contextual variable. You can do that by changing the **OnChange** property of the dropdown to the following  **Set(ResetToggle, true); Set(ResetToggle, false)** and leave the Reset property for the toggle control as **ResetToggle**

Comment: thanks it works! I will be adding more questions on other things can you please help if possible :O? @Akande Babatunde

Comment: Glad it worked, you can sure contact me when you have issues

Comment: how to contact u @Akande Babatunde